# Lost bookmark to saudi arabian q&a site on islamic questions

Tags: support

About 20yrs ago when internet was young and well before 9/11 I had found a good site answering questions about Islam and Quran from saudi arabia.

I guess this is not the right place to ask about it, but I have no place else to search or ask.

I remember some post of a muslime who had, unaware that it is prohibited by Quran, married two sisters at the same time.

I would like to have that link back, and others are welcome, too.

Comment: [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/8442/) is pretty old, I think it goes back to the late 90's.